# Prove that $n^2 \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 24)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $n$ be an odd integer not divisible by $3$. Prove that $n^2 \equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 24)$.
We just started congruences in class so I'm a little stuck as to how to solve this.

So far, I've done: $24 \mid n^2 - 1$ and since $n$ is odd, I defined $n = 2m + 1$ for some integer $m$. Plugging that in gives me $24 \mid 4m(m+1)$, and now I'm not sure what to do with this. Where did I go wrong/any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Try the congruence classes mod $3$ as well...

Comment: Trick for the future: `a\mod b` gives $$a\mod b$$ `a\pmod b` gives $$a\pmod b$$ and `a\bmod b` gives $$a\bmod b$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest an even better approach: Note that $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$. Since $n$ is odd, $n-1$ and $n+1$ are even and in specific one of these is divisible by $4$. Also, one of $n-1,n,n+1$ is divisible by $3$. By assumption, $n$ is not divisible by $3$, so one of the others must be. Combining all of these gives us the divisibility by $24$.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost done! Note that either $m$ or $m+1$ is even. And either $m$ or $m+1$ is divisible by $3$. (Why? Try modulo $3$.)

Answer (score 0):

$n=6m\pm 1$
so
$n^2
=36m^2\pm 12m+1
=12m(3m\pm 1)+1
$
and
$m(3m\pm 1)$
is even since if
$m$ is odd then
$3m\pm 1$
is even.